# Fancybox index reset when opened from hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, fancybox-2

I have a project with thumbnails that when moused over show the full-sized version in a display area div.  This is done using jQuery to pull the HTML for the full-sized images from a hidden div and display it in the visible display div.

I currently have Fancybox (ver 2.1.5) configured to work on document load.  Each of the hidden full-sized images includes a link that has the fancybox class and a rel group with the same name.

When the display area is clicked on, Fancybox opens the image as desired.  However, when the next button is clicked it always goes to the first image (including when it is the first image), and the previous button always goes to the last image (including when it is the last image).  Of course my desise would be for it to maintain the order of the images (as the links are ordered in the HTML).

Does anyone have any suggestions how this might work as I am hoping (either with jQuery or Fancybox)?

My thanks in advance to all you brilliant folks out there who generously volunteer your time and expertise!

HTML:

```
    <div class="report_container">
        <div class="report_thumbnails_container">
            <div class="report_thumbnails">
                <a href="#" page="page1"><img src="images/contents/page1_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page2"><img src="images/contents/page2_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page3"><img src="images/contents/page3_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page4"><img src="images/contents/page4_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page5"><img src="images/contents/page5_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <!--a href"#" page="page6"><img src="images/contents/page6_thumbnail.jpg"/></a-->
                <a href="#" page="page7"><img src="images/contents/page7_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page8"><img src="images/contents/page8_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page9"><img src="images/contents/page9_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page10"><img src="images/contents/page10_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page11"><img src="images/contents/page11_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page12"><img src="images/contents/page12_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <!--a href="#" page="page13"><img src="images/contents/page13_thumbnail.jpg"/></a-->
                <a href="#" page="page14"><img src="images/contents/page14_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page15"><img src="images/contents/page15_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page16"><img src="images/contents/page16_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="#" page="page17"><img src="images/contents/page17_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="report_page_container">
            <div class="page_contents"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_both"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="page_container_contents">
        <div class="page_contents" id="page1">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page1_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page1_display.jpg" width="900" height="1150" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page2">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page2_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page2_display.jpg" width="900" height="1098" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page3">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page3_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page3_display.jpg" width="900" height="1207" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page4">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page4_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page4_display.jpg" width="900" height="1091"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page5">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page5_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page5_display.jpg" width="900" height="1102"/></a>
        </div>
        <!--div class="page_contents" id="page6">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page6_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page6_display.jpg" width="900" height=""/></a>
        </div-->
        <div class="page_contents" id="page7">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page7_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page7_display.jpg" width="900" height="1154"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page8">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page8_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page8_display.jpg" width="900" height="1145"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page9">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page9_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page9_display.jpg" width="900" height="1159"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page10">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page10_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page10_display.jpg" width="900" height="1141"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page11">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page11_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page11_display.jpg" width="900" height="1138"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page12">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page12_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page12_display.jpg" width="900" height="1162"/></a>
        </div>
        <!--div class="page_contents" id="page13">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page13_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page13_display.jpg" width="900" height=""/></a>
        </div-->
        <div class="page_contents" id="page14">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page14_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page14_display.jpg" width="900" height="1110"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page15">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page15_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page15_display.jpg" width="900" height="1101"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page16">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page16_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page16_display.jpg" width="900" height="1152"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page_contents" id="page17">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page17_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page17_display.jpg" width="900" height="1154"/></a>
        </div>
        <!--div class="page_contents" id="page18">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/contents/page18_preview.jpg"><img src="images/contents/page18_display.jpg" width="900" height=""/></a>
        </div-->
    </div>
```

Code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

var page = '.page_contents#page1';
var htmlCode = $(page).html();
$('.report_page_container .page_contents').html(htmlCode);

var notClicked = true;

$('.report_thumbnails a').mouseover(function(){

    if (notClicked) {
        var page = '.page_contents#' + $(this).attr('page');
        var htmlCode = $(page).html();

        $('.report_page_container').fadeOut(0, function(){
            $('.report_page_container .page_contents').html(htmlCode);
            $('.report_page_container').fadeIn(0);
        });
    }
});

$('.report_thumbnails a').click(function(e){

    // Disables standard link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $('.report_thumbnails a').removeClass('selected');
        $('.report_thumbnails a').children().css('opacity', '1');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children().css('opacity', '.5');
        notClicked = false;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $('.report_thumbnails a').removeClass('selected');
        $('.report_thumbnails a').children().css('opacity', '1');
        notClicked = true;          
    }

    var page = '.page_contents#' + $(this).attr('page');
    var htmlCode = $(page).html();

    $('.report_page_container').fadeOut(0, function(){
        $('.report_page_container .page_contents').html(htmlCode);
        $('.report_page_container').fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: This site is not to tell you how code that you find works but to help you with your own code and problems.

Comment: Golly... my bad! Although before I posted I searched through over 20 similar questions that asked about Fancybox usage. Most were nicely answered and no one else was similarly notified about their usage. So please forgive that I thought I could do the same.